# Blu-Ray disc not being recognized in the filesystem when they are inserted into the drive.

Tags: 16.04, gnome, mount, vlc, blu-ray

This happens with some blu-ray discs and not all discs. When I insert them into my drive they just do not show up in the file system to be used by programs.(VLC/MakeMkV etc) I take out the bluray and insert a DVD and the DVD loads, so I know that the drive can mount and is connected correctly.

It seems like newer Blurays are more likely to not mount at all. I've had success with older Blurays mounting and being able to play them as per 'Playing Bluray' instructions using both makemkv and vlc.

`lshw -c disk` when a disc is inserted:

```
*-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: BDDVDRW CT10N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr1
       version: WH04
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: status=nodisc
```

What seems odd to me is that bluray is not listed as a capability. But the fact that some blurays work make it more frustrating. Any idea why this would happen?